# How can I pass """ to a Javascript function-call made inside an HTML-tag?

Tags: php, javascript, string

I have a Javascript function (named insert_formatText) which inserts text into a specified textarea. This function takes 4 parameters:
- opentag (the open tag)
- closetag (the close tag)
- formid (id-attribute value of the form)
- elementid (id-attribute value of the textarea)

My function works very well except for when you set opentag as """ and closetag as """. In that case, it simply breaks.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('"""', '"""', 'foo', 'bar');">INSERT TRIPLE-QUOTES</a>
```

### Extra Detail

I actually use PHP to loop through an array containing the opentag and closetag values as a key => value pair. In the loop, I pass those values to a function:

```
function editorButton($pre, $suf, $fid, $eid, $label){
    $str = <<<EOT
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('$pre', '$suf', '$fid', '$eid');">$label</a>
EOT;
    return $str;
}
```

So my question: is there anyway to get this to work for double-quotes without much changing? Or will I have to find a different method to generate these buttons?

Comment: Instead of `"` you could use `' + String.fromCharCode(34) + '`.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotes using a backslash in this manner:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('\"\"\"', '\"\"\"', 'foo', 'bar');">INSERT TRIPLE-QUOTES</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are inside a tag and you've opened a string as ". So you need escapes

```
<a href="javascript:;" 
   onclick="insert_formatText('\"\"\"', '\"\"\"', 'foo', 'bar');"
>INSERT TRIPLE- QUOTES</a>
```

Or the other way around, you can try this

```
<a href="" onclick='insert_formatText("\"\"\"", "\"\"\"" "foo", "bar");'>INSERT TRIPLE- QUOTES</a>
```

Comment: maybe the other way around helps? (using single quotes for the onclick, and doubles foor the formatTexst)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add slashes:

```
function editorButton($pre, $suf, $fid, $eid, $label){
    $pre = addslashes($pre);
    $suf = addslashes($suf);
    $str = <<<EOT
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('$pre', '$suf', '$fid', '$eid');">$label</a>
EOT;
    return $str;
}
```

then it will yield you:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('\"\"\"', '\"\"\"', 'foo', 'bar');">INSERT TRIPLE-QUOTES</a>
```

Comment: I attempted this JUST before you posted it, actually (inspired by the replies below). I tried it, it still does not work. I looked at the source-code and it showed exactly as you said it would. All the other buttons work fine, but not the double-quote delimited ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your quotes as entities in the html. i.e.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="insert_formatText('&quot;&quot;&quot;', '&quot;&quot;&quot;', 'foo', 'bar');">INSERT TRIPLE-QUOTES</a>
```

You can use the PHP function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for this.